# how to dynamically get the image from the windows application from database image path

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, image

I am facing a problem to save the image in folder name "Images" in my windows application. The issue is that when I select an image through save dialogbox and display it in picturebox and click save. I choose the location of windows program/images folder. It saves the picture in the application  folder as well as I entered its path in database. It saved successfully.

But my problem is that if I changed the application location (e.g. on other computer) and retrieve the image through image path saved in database. It conflict to retrieve the image.

Example:
If I save the image in `c:\document and settings\dinesh\desktop\uploadImage\Images` location and this path saves in database also. When I changed the uploadImage application location to `c:\document and settings\dinesh\MyDocuments\uploadImage`. I am sure it could not retrieve the image with database image path. Is there any solution that it will take dynamically path for the application like asp.net `~/uploadImage/Images`?

Comment: I think you need a fix directory in your app and if these images are to be needed across machines then its got be pushed into the DB

Comment: Its a small windows application. It a about database management. In this application any new user fill the form for registration and upload their photo in it. I want to save this photo in the application folder(Images) and its path save in database. When user want to update their details or photo, the details fatch from the database and photo from the application folder. is their any solution?

Comment: Why don't you save the image in the database? Why happens if the same user wants to use your application from a different computer?

Comment: Please tell me how to save image in database. If you have any code for this please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this:

```
string exedir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

string imagedir = exedir + "/uploadImage/Images";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what is this mean (assembly.getexecutingAssembly().Location) Please be clear. I could not understand.

Comment: Oh, im sorry. it returns the directory of the program which you are executing.